# How to install a rails 3 plugin and not get a Commands is not a module error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to install the following plugin:

https://github.com/eliotsykes/asset_fingerprint

```
$rails plugin install https://github.com/eliotsykes/asset_fingerprint.git
```

But getting the following error:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/railties-3.0.5/lib/rails/commands/plugin.rb:277:in `<top (required)>': Commands is not a module (TypeError)
```

Any suggestions to resolve? Thanks

**UPDATE**

```
$ cat Gemfile.lock | grep rake
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    rake (0.9.2)
  rake
```

Comment: Which rake? Please write in console `cat Gemfile.lock | grep rake` at project folder.

Comment: $ cat Gemfile.lock | grep rake
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    rake (0.9.2)
  rake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
i also got a similar error once, however when i changed to the git-read only it worked, not sure how though

```
$rails plugin install git://github.com/eliotsykes/asset_fingerprint.git
```